# ActiveX cannot create object on Set outA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Tags: outlook, windows-10, vb6

I have a legacy VB6 application to allow a user to send an email from the application itself.

```
Dim outA As Outlook.Application

Set outA = New Outlook.Application

If outA Is Nothing = True Then
    'Outlook is not open... so need to create a new outlook
    Set outA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

In Windows 7 Office 2007 it works. User can have Outlook open and it works with no issues.

In Windows 10 Office 2016 this code does not work. It gives me an error on

```
Set outA = New Outlook.Application.
```

If Outlook is not open, the code works. I'm only getting this error if Outlook is open.

The error is...

> ActiveX cannot create object error 429.

I have local privelages on my computer.
If I open my VB6 .exe explicitly as ADMIN and Outlook as ADMIN as well - the code gives me no issues.
I have UAC prompt disabled.
I cannot give ADMIN rights to user.

Am I missing a dll or something? I have a few more applications that have been used in Windows 7 and I have not had this issue.

Comment: I should note that I've already tried - GetObject(,"Outlook.Application") - same issue

Answer (score 2):

Keep the early binding for development and once complete, scrap it for the late bind. Don't forget to remove the reference to Microsoft Outlook xx Object Library in VBE.

Early binding:

```
Dim outA As Outlook.Application
Set outA = New Outlook.Application
```

Late Binding:

```
Dim outA As Object
Set outA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

The reason is that early binding references a specific version of Outlook e.g. Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library which is specific for Office 2010, so if it's not available it throws an error. The reference itself is marked with a "missing".

The late binding's `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` takes care of that.

Comment: But the reference is there as Microsoft Outlook 16.0 ObjectLibrary. Either way regardless of whether I go with Early or Late binding I get an error. The problem is with me having Outlook open. When it's Open i get an error, when it's not open I dont have any issues. Unless I have both the Outlook and .exe open explicitly RUN AS ADMIN (on top of local privelages). If I don't get the ACTIVEX error - i get a popup that says Component Request Pending. The action cannot be completed because the other application is busy

Comment: @Kostas K.  - absolutely not. Develop your code using the lowest supported version of Outlook. Newer versions are always backward compatible.

Comment: Yes, I tried that for the last 20 years ever since Outlook 97 came out. When you use early binding, your app ends up calling CoCreateInstance with the CLSID of Outlook.Application - it is {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, and it has not changed since Outlook 97.

Answer (score -1):

Repare office and ok (for me that was the solution)